# HTACCESS Redirect For Ecommerce Site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, e-commerce

Could you please help to do a one off redirect in htaccess file from:

```
/something-something-something-something-c-2_19_70.html
```

to this type of file that does not have the number -2_:

```
/something-something-something-something-c-19_70.html
```

I am sure there is a short code that will get applied to all url of that type

Thank you very much in advance

David

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect /something-something-something-something-c-2_19_70.html 
# to /something-something-something-something-c-19_70.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)2_(.*)$ $1$2 [L,NC,R]

# redirect /ethical-jewellery-silver-c-2_19.html to /silver-c-19.html
RewriteRule ^[^-]+-[^-]+-([^-]+-)([^-]+-)2_(.*)$ $1$2$3 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful in explaining what didn't work :) btw this same rule is redirecting URI `/something-something-something-something-c-2_19_70.html` to `/something-something-something-something-c-19_70.html` in my testing. I suggest you to post your complete .htaccess in your question so I can investigate further.

Comment: I need to redirect this url: http://www.oriajewellery.co.uk/ethical-jewellery-silver-c-2_19.html

Comment: both have the same content and need to be consolidated to get rid of duplicate content. The urls are dynamically generated but do not have an id. All the examples on the web do not seem to work. Any ideas how to make it work? Thank you

Comment: As per your question you wanted to redirect `/something-something-something-something-c-2_19_70.html` to `/something-something-something-something-c-19_70.html` but your comment is saying a different thing. Anyway pls check my edited answer as per your comment.

Comment: Hi, Just tried and it did not work. Maybe there is something in the file that overwrites it? Do you have an email address so I could send you the htaccess file code? It does not fit here. Thank you very much for your help!:-)

Comment: Howsoever big it is, pls post your .htaccess here. The idea behind SO is to get your answers on SO itself by providing full details of your problem. That way other readers facing similar problems can also benefit.